# CRUD Write specific application needs more than 7600 req/min for FREE Account

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application which does CRUD ( write specific ) operation very frequently on the app engine and at times it might exceed the Free limit of 7600 req/min. Is there any way to increase this limit?

P.S. I understand that paid account will boost it to 30000 req/min but it don't want to use that.

Is there anyway to use the concept of sparse files and send files instead of using 4KB pages. Because the response to the CRUD operation only takes certain bytes and all the other bytes are wasted.

Regards

Comment: Where did you find this 7600req/min. limit? (sorry, but don't expect for an answer to a question like "my app use too many ressource, how can i improve it?"...)

Comment: there is no such thing as a request limit. never heard about that

Comment: @ Greg : Sorry if you find this question to be a bit lame. But i found this limit from " Beginning Java Google App Engine " book. To what the book says " Requests(all request to applications) Maximum rate Free Account -> 7600 req / min. much appreciated.

Comment: Your book was written in 2009. Much has changed in two year and a half.

Comment: The reference docs are online: you should always consult those first: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas

Comment: Oops..Sorry bout it.. will check the online content. thanks a lot

Comment: So... you want to do more than 120QPS, and you don't want to pay anything for it? Don't you think that's a bit unreasonable?

Answer (score 2):

Note: it's hard to give a generic cost-saving advice - it all depends on what your app is doing. Here are some basic tips:

Saving on Datastore usage - read [billing docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing) first to understand what the cost structure is.

1. Most important: use memcache whenever possible, especially for caching results of complex queries.
2. If possible use `get()` instead of `query()`. They are half cheaper.
3. Don't index properties that are not used in queries. Indexes are very expensive - they cost on every entity create/update/delete.
4. Important: Don't use `offset` in queries - this is a HUGE waste of resources. It actually reads all entities up to `offset+limit` (and charges you for this) then just returns `limit` entities to application: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_fetch

General advice for web apps - cache, cache, cache: if your HTTP GETs are idempotent (they change based on parameters, but not with time), then you can set cache headers so that requests will be served by Google cache infrastructure (which is enabled for all GAE apps).

Comment: He did not even bother to clarify that, but its application is in Java not Python

Comment: Again apologies... the application is in java.

Comment: Not sure how it being java changes any of Peter's advice. It's all still exactly correct. Also make sure you understand data modeling for no-sql databases, try to avoid any join-like queries (yeah, there are no joins, but I mean try to only load 1 type of object for each fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Still kinda clueless on what you're doing, but Google App Engine on the free tier is likely the wrong product for you.

While I don't know of any 7600 req/min limitation, there's a 50k daily datastore write operation limit, and a 50k datastore read operation limit.  Assuming that each HTTP request only makes one write op, your app would only be able to run for 6.6 minutes a day on the free tier.

I have no idea on what you're talking about sparse files or 4k pages so I'm downvoting on an unclear question.